# Explicit calculation of simplicial homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Is it possible to calculate simplicial homology of $n$-dimensional simplex just by definition, without using homotopy invariance of homology(or it's equality to singular or cellular ones)?

I've done it for $n\leq4$ by explicit calculation of $\partial$, but this method doesn't seems to be easy generalizable.

UPD: I'm considering strucuture of simplicial complex on simplex there simplices of complex are all faces of simplex. I'm using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_homology) definition of simplicial homology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Yes you can. You won't mention the homotopy invariance, but  you will use a contraction.

Say you have a contractible space $X$, like your simplex. It comes with a map
$$\phi\colon X\times [0,1]\to X$$
$\phi_{|X\times \{1\}} = \text{Id}_X$ and $\phi_{|X\times \{0\}} \equiv x_0$

( $X$ contracts to the point  $x_0$ ).

Using this we'll construct a map from singular $n$-simplexes on $X$ to singular $n+1$-simplexes on $X$ as follows:

Let $f\colon \Delta_n \to X$ a singular simplex. This gets us a map 
$$f \times \text{Id}_I \colon \Delta_n \times I \to X\times I $$
Compose it with $\phi$ to get a map from $\Delta_n \times I$ to $X$ that takes the value $x_0$ on $\Delta_n \times \{0\}$, so it factors through $\Delta_n \times I/\Delta_n \times \{0\}$. But $\Delta_n \times I/\Delta_n \times \{0\}$ homeomorphic to $\Delta_{n+1}$ in a natural way. We got ourselves a singular $n+1$-simplex.

In this way we get a map of complexes $\tau_n\colon C_{n}(X) \to C_{n+1}(X)$ for all $n\ge 0$.

This allows us to show that the (reduced) homology is zero. Hint: calculate
$$d \tau + \tau d$$ in each dimension.

Comment: The homotopy invariance is more involved. The homotopy gets us a map from prism $\Delta_n\times I$ to $X$ that is not constant on a base of the prism. Hence, one needs to use a canonical decomposition of the prism into $n+1$-dimensional simplexes, not too bad though. More delicate to prove is excision (or, Maier-Vietoris). There, barycentric decompositions are used and the reasoning is more topology-heavy.

Comment: If I got your answer right, you're considering singular homology, but my question was about simplicial ones.

Comment: Oh,yes, indeed, I did consider singular homology. About simplicial homology, there are several variants, all giving naturally isomorphic results. Can you describe the definition of simplicial homology you are using? In any case, the calculations are all algebra and some combinatorics.

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: OK, it appears to use oriented simplices. No topology is involved. To show the triviality of the reduced homology show the existence of an algebraic homotopy operator. Basically it's like this: Fix a vertex of the simples $s_0$. Define $\tau(s_{i_0}, \ldots s_{i_k}) = (s_0, s_{i_0}, \ldots s_{i_k})$ if $0$ is not among $(i_0, \ldots, i_k)$ and zero otherwise. Note that we get a map from $k$ chains to $k+1$ chains, for all $k$. Again, calculate $d \tau + \tau d$.